# setting the PATH for Git (not for me)

Tags: mac-osx, git

I'm running OSX 10.6.5 with Git 1.7.1

I have git installed in a non-standard location (though that really should be the standard on a mac;-) in /Library/Frameworks/Git.framework. My own PATH is set fine, git works fine, until... I set up a pre-commit hook with a Ruby script:

```
$ git commit -m "added some Yard documentation"
.git/hooks/pre-commit: line 1: #!/usr/bin/env: No such file or directory
```

The pre-commit.sample runs ok, so it appears that git can't find /usr/bin/env, or much else as I've tried shebanging it directly to ruby etc. Just /bin/sh is ok.

So, where does Git get it's PATH? because it's not using mine or this wouldn't be happening. And more to the point, how do I get it to see /usr/bin/env ?

I've tested the ruby script already, it works.

---

Just to add:

```
$ cat /etc/paths                    
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/usr/local/bin

$ cat /etc/paths.d/git
/Library/Frameworks/Git.framework/Programs
```

---

The first few lines of the Ruby script (which runs via ./pre-commit or ruby pre-commit)

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby -wKU

class String
  def expand_path
    File.expand_path self
  end

  def parent_dir
    File.dirname self.expand_path
  end
end
```

Comment: If its failing on an absolute executable, its not doing this because of your path.  It means that its actively unable to find the command `/usr/bin/env` on your system, and your PATH has nothing to do with it.

Comment: It's not saying it can't find "/usr/bin/env", it's saying it can't find "#!/usr/bin/env". If you show the first few lines of the file, we might be able to see the problem.

Comment: @Redmumba: That should give a "bad interpreter message", but you're right about the absolute path.

Comment: You are absolutely right; I was looking over the message and noticed it was saying it couldn't find `#!/usr/bin/env`, not just `/usr/bin/env`.

Comment: Are you sure that's the exact contents of your git hook?  I.e., `cat .git/hooks/pre-commit`?

Comment: yes. Because you're all saying it's not the paths I just tried cp'ing the file somewhere else to run it, and it had the same issue. Copied the text into a new file and it runs ok. Cp'ed it back and it works. There is nothing in the ls's I ran on the previous file or it's metadata that I can see that would screw this up, but it did. Thanks everyone, I've given upvotes to you all. Anyone know how to close this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File was corrupted somehow from the time I'd copied it in to .git/hooks, a new file with same code fixed it. Many thanks to @Redmumba and @Dennis Williamson for letting me know I was looking in the wrong place.

Comment: Awesome!  Please mark your answer as correct, just so the question will be closed off. :)